# SVG D3: Display an element only within a specific group or a specific SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Is there a way to display a D3 element only within a specific group?

Lets say, I have 2 rect elements, side by side within an SVG. And I want to show a circle only within the first rect. If the circle moved to the second rect element position, the circle shouldn't show over second rect.

This can be achieved by using a SVG element within a SVG element like bellow:

```
<svg id="outer">
  <svg id="inner1">
  </svg>
  <svg id="inner2">
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Same can be seen in the folowing link: https://hitokun-s.github.io/old/demo/path-between-two-svg.html

But If I use it like this, I'm unable to style the inner SVGs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "But If I use it like this, I'm unable to style the inner SVGs." I don't understnd that sentence. What is hindering you?

Comment: It is possible by using 3 [`viewBox`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute)es.

Comment: @ccprog What I meant was, If I use inner and outer SVGs. I wan't to add a border to inner SVG. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, with `viewBox` it is possible to have a the SVG within an SVG. But I'm unable to style the inner SVG. I want to add a border to the inner SVG.

Comment: SVG does't have borders. Just use `<rect>` with stroke and without fill to  simulate it.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, SVGs can have borders. Please see the link I have given in the example. It's not just the border. I can't have any styles (ex: background-color, border, fill) in the "inner" SVG.
Any Style is acceptable by the "outer" SVG.

Comment: Use [browser development tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) for above mentioned example and you will see rectangles is used to simulate borders for inner `<svg>`s.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, Yes the rect is used for adding the border. For my solution, I'll have to use nested SVGs and then use recttangkes for styling.

Answer (score -3):

Answer to my own Question, after hours of searching.

This can be achieved by having the "inner" SVG inside a `div` element.

```
<svg id="outer">
  <foreignObject>
    <div>
      <svg id="inner" style="border-radius: 20px; border: 1px solid red;">
      </svg>
    </div>                
  </foreignObject>
</svg
```

`Div` element can be placed within the `svg` using the `foreignObject` element. Then the "inner" SVG is considered as an "outer" element and the styles can be applied.

Hope this helps to any other poor soul.